# Permission Denied, Error 70 When You Use OpenTextFile Statement in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am getting the error Run-time error '70': Permission Denied.

While debugging we Identified error is coming from the below line:

```
Set objFileCheck = objFSCheck.OpenTextFile(strDirName & "\" & cnstCheckVersion_Filename, ForReading, TristateFalse)
```

But when the user is retrying he/she could not get the same error. What might be the root cause for this error while opening the textfile in read mode.

I really appreciate the help.

Comment: The user may not have the rights to access this folder on the network

Comment: Retrying after getting this error, user could not get the same error. :(

Comment: I can't say for sure without having access to your computer, but I can tell you that error 70 also happens when the path isn't correct, particularly when dealing with opening and saving files. You have to use the full path name to get to the file. Perhaps the user's computer is mapped differently than yours.

Comment: To avoid hardcoding value of the path we used variables like strDirName for the directory and cnstCheckVersion_Filename for the file name. When the user retrying after getting this error or after clicking on debug it is working fine. So some where issue is with this file is used by some other process or it is already opened. So if any one could help me then I would really appreciate.

Comment: In Excel VBA Macro(.xltm) file we have implemented a mechanism that tries opening the text file which causing run time error, after a 5 sec waiting time before it fails.
Code: Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: In Excel VBA Macro(.xltm) file we have implemented a mechanism that tries opening the text file which causing run time error, after a 5 sec waiting time before it fails.
Code: Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))